# troubleshooting: bash script overwrites each iteration within a for loop instead of appending each iteration

Tags: bash

I'm trying to troubleshoot a very simple bash script that is not working as expected (code below). It is supposed to run the zgrep command on each line in the input file "myQueries.txt" (e.g., "^dog ") and append the output (e.g., "^dog 0.934 0.231") as a new line for the file "output.txt". It appears to be running the command on each line of the input file, but it only appends the result of the last iteration in the loop. If I manually run the zgrep command for each line directly in the Terminal (MacOS 13.3.1), it works perfectly, so the zgrep command appears to be working. If I run the bash script multiple times, then it appends the result of the last iteration in each run to the output.txt file. But for some reason it just 'eats' the results of the other iterations.

Can anyone help me identify the problem in the script? Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat myQueries.txt); do
    zgrep -m 1 "$line" dataset.gz >> output.txt
done
```

Comment: That's what would happen if you used `>` instead of `>>`. I don't see how it can happen if your code is as you show.

Comment: I'll bet `myQueries.txt` has CRLF newlines, so the other iterations aren't matching at all.

Comment: Use `hexdump -C` or `cat -A` or another tool that shows hidden content to review your output file.

Comment: BTW, instead of using `>>` inside the loop, use `done > output.txt`.

Comment: BTW, also see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Also, it would be **much** more efficient to start zgrep only once, and feed it your whole `myQueries.txt` file as an argument; there's no reason to run a new copy of zgrep per query.

Comment: ...well, there's _a_ reason, the `-m 1`; if you really need to enforce the "only one match per query" aspect, it might make more sense to write this in awk -- an awk script will still give you the ability to read each input file _only once_ instead of needing to do this O(n\*m) loop, and it's a dynamic enough language that you can delete things from an array you use to track the patterns that still need to be matched dynamically.

Comment: Circling back to the question, though -- please try building a reproducer in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/, or at least testing that you can build a reproducer that creates its own input files (or doesn't need input files at all) and still can cause the issue -- that way we can see the problem ourselves, instead of needing to make guesses about the true format and contents of your input files.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses! It turned out to be the (undisplayed) newline character sequence in the input.txt file that didn't match up with those in the dataset.gz file (thanks, Barmar!), except for the last line in the file, where I'm guessing that the lack of a final \n allowed zgrep to match the query that I *thought* I'd entered.